# closed complement

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

How can we show that $c_0$ has no closed complement in $l^\infty$.  Similarly $C([0,1])$ has no closed complement in $B([0,1])$

Comment: To put it a little bluntly: what's your motivation for asking? (see http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask#motivation)

Comment: $c_0$ is complemented in any separable superspace, David. It is natural to ask if it is complemented in any superspace, which is equivalent to the first question because `$\ell_\infty$` is injective.

Comment: @Bill That's a nice way to look at it :)

Comment: Agree with @David. It's not for answerers to provide motivation!


Answer (score 2):

For the first question, see Theorem 2.5.5 in the book of Albiac and Kalton.  The second question is immediate from the first and the easy fact that $C[0,1]$ has a complemented subspace isometric to $c_0$.